# Do I need a license to use a USB-A plug on my power cable?

Tags: usb, usb-device, licensing

I want to make a product that has a power cable with a USB-A plug on it.

There is no USB socket on the device, the cable just enters the device, similar to the [HomePod mini](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/3a4dbb5c818caabc41c65d3d8feb213fa49bfa86/0_1_5456_3273/master/5456.jpg?width=620&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=914a5ba8ca3d92951e4c76ebe4393b30).

The idea is to instruct users in the user manual and on the website to "use a USB-A power supply to power the device".

Would this violate trademarked use of the word "USB"? Since I am not claiming that the device itself is a USB device?

Does it count as ["nominative fair use"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_use)?

The question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/450494/are-usb-protocol-and-connector-free-or-are-they-patented), because my question specifically asks about referring to a USB charger by name in the context of a non-USB device that simply uses USB for power delivery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are USB protocol and connector free or are they patented?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/450494/are-usb-protocol-and-connector-free-or-are-they-patented)

Comment: @crasic No, because that question does talk about USB-devices, while my device is not a USB device, it merely uses a USB plug on its power cable.

Comment: Don't tell an end user to look for a USB-A port - it will just confuse them.  Everyone knows them as just plain "USB" ports - it's obvious what shape fits in what hole.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word "USB" is not trademarked, you can use it any way you want.

The only USB-ish words trademarked are "USB Type-C", "USB-C" and "USB4".
There are also a number of USB logos that cannot be used without permission, and some other USB related names such as "SUPERSPEEDPLUS" etc.

You can see more details in the [USB logo usage guidelines](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/usb-if_logo_usage_guidelines_final_as_of_november_2_2018_locked_0.pdf) and find [registered trademarks at Justia](https://trademarks.justia.com/owners/usb-implementers-forum-inc-2194643/index.html).

[image: Snippet from USB logo guidelines]

Also worth a note; the traditional "trident" logo is not trademarked and can be used without permission from USB IF.

[image: Trident logo]

Comment: Does this mean that “USB-A” is also not trademarked? Unlike USB-C?

Comment: @KonstantinSchubert Indeed.

Comment: What about the original (non SuperSpeed,) 'trident' logo - have they given up on that one?

Comment: @brhans Yes, the standard trident logo can also be used without any permission from USB IF. Check out this document from FTDI for example, chapter 3.1: https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/TN_114_USB-Device-Testing-and-Marking.pdf